# how to create a "profanity filter" in discord.js

Tags: arrays, node.js, json, discord.js

I want to add a profanity checker. I have a list of 2000 words that I want to be blocked.

I know about `if (message.content.includes())` but am unsure of how to check for any of the words in a json array.

```js
// i know to import the json file
const profanity = require('./File.json')
```

I also want to check, i would setup the array like this

```
array: 
  [
   "word1", "word2", "word3" 
  ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### [`RegExp#test()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test)

Consider using a [Regular Expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to match a word within a given string. Be sure to [escape characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3561711) as necessary considering that the regex wouldn't be hard-coded. [This site](https://regex101.com) can be useful for easily testing and creating a regex (make sure to select EMCA/JS as the flavor).

```js
const regex = /\btoday\b/i; // \b is a word boundary, i flag means case insensitive
const str = 'How are you today?';
console.log(regex.test(str));
```

You can certainly develop a more complex regex to counter against bypass tactics like adding a `-` or spacing the letters out.

---

#### Example

Now, a simple example employing a RegExp object to determine which filtered words the string includes:

```js
const words = ['dog', 'cat', 'fish'];
const str = 'My cat ate my fish, then my dogs barked.'; // "dogs" will not be caught

const found = words.filter((word) => {
  const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${word}\\b`, 'i');
  // \b is an escape sequence (backspace) within a string. In order to actually
  // include \b in the string, the \ needs to be escaped with another \ .

  return regex.test(str);
});

console.log(found);
```

---

#### Implementation

You can easily implement this system into your client's `message` event. If you don't need to know which words the author used, I'd suggest the following:

```js
const profanity = require('./profanity.json'); // assuming this is an array of words

client.on('message', (message) => {
  if (message.content) {
    const profane = !!profanity.find((word) => {
      const regex = new RegExp(`\\b${word}\\b`, 'i'); // if the phrase is not alphanumerical,
      return regex.test(message.content);             // you may need to escape tokens
    });

    if (profane) {
      return message.delete()
        .catch(console.error);
    }
  }
});
```

It's also possible to create a single regex to test rather than multiple, which may be much faster. A possible solution would be `` new RegExp(`\\b(${profanity.join('|')})\\b`, 'i') ``; again, keep in mind to escape tokens in order to match the characters literally.

Comment: This isn't the right way to design a filter. Guess which blacklisted words will flag `glass`, `cucumber` and many other regular common terms. I would strongly recommend using regex or string similarity.